# iOS Best Practice Preloading Data for App

Tags: ios, database, uinavigationcontroller

I have an App that works from a Tab Bar Controller. But before I get to that menu I need to preload and run some database checks. What is the best way to do this as it only needs to run once and not every time you return to the Home Page. This needs to sit between the Launch Images and the Home Page.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing it in the app delegate's application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method? That's where I initialize the Core Data stack.

You could execute the check on a background thread, so that your views continue to load.